# console debugging visual studio 2015, like Xcode feature

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, is there a way similar to Xcode that when you have a breakpoint, you could type out an expression and have the output displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS that is done with the Immediate window.

...except in client-side web-debugging scenarios when there's a special "F12" window for DOM and JavaScript debugging.